# How to use Serial as an interrupt for other functions

Tags: arduino, serial-port, interrupt, led, fastled

I'm making an LED control program (using FastLED, of course) and using Serial (with the Serial monitor) to control it. I just connected it via USB and for the most part it works just fine. However, I noticed with the long, flashing routines that I couldn't stop them and make the LEDs do something else. The flash routine in my code is very simple:

```cpp
void flash(CRGB color, int count, int del){
  for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
    if(pause){
      break;
    }
    fillLeds(color.r, color.g, color.b);
    milliDelay(del);
    fillLeds(0,0,0);
    milliDelay(del);
  }
}
```

With `fillLeds(r,g,b)` being a *for* loop, looping through and setting all LEDs to a certain color, and `milliDelay` is just `delay()` using `millis` and not the `delay()` function.

I need to be able to pause not just this, but other functions as well (probably using `break;`) and then execute other code. It seems easy, right? Well, I've noticed that when I send a byte over Serial, it goes into this "queue," if you will, and then is sequentially read.

I can’t have this happen. I need the next byte entering Serial to activate some kind of event that pauses the other `flash()` function running, and then be used. I have implemented this like:

```cpp
void loop()
{
  if (Serial.available() > 0)
  {
    int x = Serial.read();
    Serial.print(x);
    handleRequest(x);
  }

  FastLED.show();
  FastLED.delay(1000 / UPDATES_PER_SECOND);
}
```

Where `handleRequest(x);` is just a long *switch* statement with calls to the flash method, with different colors being used, etc.

How can I make the Arduino pause other loops whenever a new byte is received, instead of adding it to this "queue" to be acted upon later? If this is not possible thanks for reading anyway. I've tried using `serialEvent()` which doesn't appear to work.

Comment: why do you say serialEvent is not functional?

Comment: Depending on your Arduino, you may need to implement `serialEventRun` instead of `serialEvent`.

Comment: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/4347/guide-to-code-for-multitasking-and-non-blocking-timers

Comment: Re *"I've tried using serialEvent() which doesn't appear to work."*: That may be because serialEvent() is ***line-oriented*** (not very clear in the documentation, absent in the code comments, and misleading in the example code). That is, a newline (whatever that is. ASCII 13?) is required before serialEvent is called. The canonical is *[Arduino "SerialEvent" example code doesn't work on my Arduino Nano. I can't receive serial data. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67013619/)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need two loops. You have one, which is your main loop, and you can add another (like a multi threading) with the TimerOne library. Like this:

```
Timer1.initialize(your desired delay in this loop);
Timer1.attachInterrupt(your desired function in this loop);
```

So maybe you can add an *if* statement with a variable in your second loop to prevent some function and update the variable in your first loop or something like that.

Comment: I think this will work, i was considering multithreading but didnt know how to do it on an arduino

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you want interrupt-like functionality when a new byte arrives:

Unfortunately, *serialEvent()* is not a true interrupt. It only runs at the end of *loop()*, if there is serial data available.

However, *serialEvent()* is just a function, and there isn't any reason why you can't call it in your code as often as you like. This is effectively polling for new serial data as often as possible. So, while your loops are running, call *serialEvent()* during your delays and handle the serial data there.

You may need to restructure your code to avoid recursion though. If *flash* calls *serialEvent()*, which calls *flash*, which calls *serialEvent*, etc... then you may end up overflowing the stack.